# Invalid properties for React Three (react-three/drei)'s Text component [TypeScript build error]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

## The Problem

##### Summary

I'm trying to create a VR web application using React Three (along with some companion XR libraries).

I'm running into a TypeScript error at build time. It seems as though I'm missing some properties while constructing the Text component (imported from [react-three/drei](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-three/drei)). I have the same exact code as some official demos, and I even see the same error in those [playground editors](https://codesandbox.io/s/8i9ro?file=/src/index.tsx:0-1721), but somehow it builds in the playground editors anyways. I am using Webpack in my project which utilizes ts-loader to *try* to build my ts/tsx files.

##### Error Message

The TypeScript error that it tries to render is too long, so it's hard to tell exactly what is going on. I think it will be more helpful to see my code (below) along with the Text component's [source code](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/master/src/core/Text.tsx) (below). Here is the error message:

> TS2740: Type '{ children: string; position: number[]; fontSize: number; color: string; anchorX: "center"; anchorY: "middle"; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Omit<ExtendedColors<Overwrite<any, NodeProps<any, any>>>, NonFunctionKeys<{ position?: any; up?: any; scale?: any; rotation?: any; matrix?: any; quaternion?: any; layers?: any; dispose?: () => void; }>> & { ...; } & EventHandlers & { ...; }, "color" | ... 110 more ... | "debugSDF">': name, type, id, material, and 71 more.

## Code Snippet

Here is a relevant snippet of my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from '@react-three/drei';
import '@react-three/fiber';

function Button() {
  return (
    <Text position={[0, 0, 0.06]} fontSize={0.05} color="#000" anchorX="center" anchorY="middle">
      Hello, Virtual World!
    </Text>
  )
}

export default Button;
```

And here are the official demo apps I referenced:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/8i9ro?file=/src/index.tsx:0-1721
- https://codesandbox.io/s/8w8hm?file=/src/App.tsx

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of React application code]

## I've Tried

- I've tried looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei/blob/master/src/core/Text.tsx) for the Text component
- Being very declarative with the children property's type - Strictly defining it as the React.ReactNode type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bandaid fix for this solution is to use `{/* @ts-expect-error */}` on the line above the error to allow for a build. Until @react-three/drei is updated, I believe this is the only solution.

Here is the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments) for `@ts-expect-error`

Alternatively, you can ignore all TypeScript errors for an entire file. This can be accomplished by adding the `// @ts-nocheck` comment at the top of the file.